# GetResource returning null depending on file separator

Tags: java

I have the following code.

```
URL resourcePath = this.getClass().getResource( File.separator + folder);
Objects.requireNonNull(resourcePath, "Path must not be null.");
```

Running on Windows, File.separator is giving me "\", when using `"\" + folder`, the `getResource` method returns null, using `"/" + folder` works correctly.

Comment: Resources are URLs, not file paths. They should always use forward slashes. They are also read-only

Comment: The resources are items packaged along with your jar. It's an url pointing to the correct path wtihin the zip file that is the jar. You aren't accessing a file on the local file system.